Pueden las ontologías mejorar a la metodología RAG a mejorar la parte de las buquedas a la base de datos?
Quiero construir una IA que me permita obtener información de una base de datos por medio de lenguaje natural usando RAG.
He estado aprendiendo un poco sobre modelos de conocimiento como ontologías y grafos de conocimientos
Aquí unas de las fuentes que he consultado:

Resource 1
Resource 2
Resource 3
Resource 4

Me percaté de que es posible convertir información no estructurada en información estructurada
Constructing Knowledge graphs from text using Open AI functions
Tambien me percaté de que es posible autogenerar queries usando graphQL
Tambien estudié un poquito sobre Retrieval-Augmented Generation aka RAG
What is RAG
Alguien me podría explicar si usar una ontología puede ayudarle a un LLM a autogenerar queries correctamente de una manera que me de certeza absoluta de que el query es correcto y represente el requirimiento de datos (inicialmente dado en texto)
Mi idea que la ontología le ayude a un segundo LLM entrenado para generar solamente queries en GraphQL para cubrir la parte de querying dentro del proceso de RAG.
Me gustaría saber si hay alguna alternativa mejor y si es posible y eficiente el desarrollo de lo que estoy planteando porfavor ayudenme :D
